# iOS13 and iOS12 iframe crossdomain setcookies policy is different

Tags: html, ios, web, mobile

iOS 12 first time cannot set cookies, but its work after 2nd tried.

iOS 13 cannot set cookies even refresh the page many times.

Anyone face this new issue?
or have the solution for setcookies

My situation as below
step 1 :Site A > Site B
        - site B will set cookie

step 2 : site B return a response link for site A
        - site A use the cookies set at site B and then use the value to append in response link